# Selecting from EAV returns rows twice

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I have the following tables

```
contacts
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╗
║ contactId ║ projectId ║ lastName ║   type    ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╣
║         1 ║         1 ║ Foo      ║ architect ║
║         2 ║         1 ║ Owner 1  ║ owner     ║
║         3 ║         1 ║ Owner 2  ║ owner     ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╝

projectDetails
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ projectId ║ projectName ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║         1 ║ Bar         ║
║         2 ║ Fizz        ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

And I'm trying to select the projectName, as well as all relevant contact people by searching for a contact person's last name. The code I'm using it to do this is

```
SELECT `det`.`projectName`, `owner`.`lastName` as `ownerLast`, `architect`.`lastName` as `archLast`,
FROM `projectDetails` as `det`
LEFT JOIN `contacts` as `owner`
    ON `owner`.`projectId` = `det`.`projectId` AND `owner`.`type`="owner"
LEFT JOIN `contacts` as `architect`
    ON `architect`.`projectId` = `det`.`projectId` AND `architect`.`type`="architect"
WHERE `architect`.`lastName` = "Foo"
```

This generates two rows

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ projectName ║ ownerLast ║ archLast ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ Bar         ║ Owner1    ║ Foo      ║
║ Bar         ║ Owner2    ║ Foo      ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Which I suppose makes sense but is not what I'm looking for.
Is there a way to aggregate results of the same type, for example into something like

```
╔═════════════╦════════════════╦══════════╗
║ projectName ║   ownerLast    ║ archLast ║
╠═════════════╬════════════════╬══════════╣
║ Bar         ║ Owner1, Owner2 ║ Foo      ║
╚═════════════╩════════════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Also, your second join is an inner join - as can be illustrated by executing `EXPLAIN EXTENDED [YOUR QUERY]`, followed by `SHOW WARNINGS;`

Comment: Oh, and also your query is obviously invalid, so you're not quite telling us the truth!

Comment: @Strawberry, I left a comma by mistake at the end of my SELECT query. Sorry about that. I'll probably end up doing it in php, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group_concat()`

```
SELECT `det`.`projectName`, group_concat(`owner`.`lastName`) as `ownerLast`, `architect`.`lastName` as `archLast`,
FROM `projectDetails` as `det`
LEFT JOIN `contacts` as `owner`
    ON `owner`.`projectId` = `det`.`projectId` AND `owner`.`type`="owner"
LEFT JOIN `contacts` as `architect`
    ON `architect`.`projectId` = `det`.`projectId` AND `architect`.`type`="architect"
WHERE `architect`.`lastName` = "Foo"
group by `det`.`projectName`,`architect`.`lastName`
```

Answer (score 1):

use `group_concat()`

```
SELECT `det`.`projectName`, group_concat( `owner`.`lastName`) as `ownerLast`, `architect`.`lastName` as `archLast`,
FROM `projectDetails` as `det`
LEFT JOIN `contacts` as `owner`
    ON `owner`.`projectId` = `det`.`projectId` AND `owner`.`type`="owner"
LEFT JOIN `contacts` as `architect`
    ON `architect`.`projectId` = `det`.`projectId` AND `architect`.`type`="architect"
WHERE `architect`.`lastName` = "Foo"
group by `det`.`projectName`,archLast
```

Comment: That works like a charm thanks. How would you change it if you wanted to check if ANY type in the `contacts` table had a duplicate row. I tried adding group_concat(`architect`.`lastName`) and then grouping by `owner`.`lastName` as well but it went back to returning two rows.

Comment: @ConstantineLoukas actually that will not be duplicated because that field is in group by clause

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain properly. Say you had 10 projects, some had 2 Owners, some 2 Architects, some 1 Owner and 1 Architect and some only 1 Owner or 1 Architect. Is there some way to modify the query above to accommodate that or should I just query all the contacts for this project and then do any grouping on the application level using php?

Comment: @ConstantineLoukas You should change `WHERE` to `AND`